# Is there a way to make a line break in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm importing  files from a unicode .txt. I have several hundred lines, and used an Excel macro to split them (I would like to use a database, but we cannot due to certain regulations). An example file would be:

```
Office Name: "Blue";    LastYTD:    38.55%  ;   ThisYTD:    4.50%   ;
```

How can I make a line break after each ;? I would like to add it directly into the Excel file before it is split if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Could please provide some more context? Are you having this data as a *string* in JavaScript? How are Excel and JavaScript related?

Answer (score 2):

You can make an array of lines with `.split()` and join it back into a string:

```
text.split(';').join('\n');
```

Or just replace them:

```
text.replace(/;/g, '\n');
```

`\n` is the escape sequence for a newline.